# Windows 255 character path/file name limit

Tags: windows-server-2003

..that applies sometimes, depending on the application, but not all the time, depending on the application..

WTF and how the heck do you all deal with this? I have users who are able to create insanely long filenames and paths, yet who aren't then able to open those files and folders in certain applications, with seemingly no way at all for me to stop them from doing it.

I can't be the only one finding it an issue..

Comment: IMHO this misses a clear question. "How the heck do you deal with this?" is probably opinion based. What do you want to achieve? Block long files? Be able to open such files? Find and rename such files?

Answer (score 1):

Path length limitations are a bummer. Fortunately you're not the only one who has thought about it. There's a [series of blog postings about long paths in .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2007/02/13/long-paths-in-net-part-1-of-3-kim-hamilton.aspx) that can give you some background on the status of long path support in .NET. There's a least one [library that adds long path support](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Long%20Path&referringTitle=Home) that you can use (license permitting, of course).

Comment: Honestly, it's beyond a joke.  I have users who create these abominations (10/10 for organisation though) and then call me when they're unable to archive them - admittedly this may be a limitation of the archiving media, but it still highlights the fact that I can't stop them from doing it.

Comment: The craziness of excessive user-create paths always seems to bite me during file server migrations.